# Cannot initialize Integer variable

Tags: java, class, integer, initialization, naming-conventions

**This is a self-answered question!**

I'm trying to initialize an `Integer` variable with a value, but it's not working as expected. It gives me different errors.

What I've tried so far:

```
public class Integer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num1 = 42;               // Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer
        Integer num2 = (Integer)42;      // Cannot cast from int to Integer
        Integer num3 = new Integer(42);  // The constructor Integer(int) is undefined
    }
}
```

What's the issue here? How can I set the value of my `Integer` properly?

Comment: you try to assign an int to a object of typ integer and you are created this class by your own.

Comment: You can use `java.lang.Integer num1 = 42` and so on....but it is not a good habit to use same names of built-in classes.

Comment: To avoid confusion you should always clearly indicate that you are posting a self-answered question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I thought, if I answer this question the same time by myself, everyone knows, that it's a self-answered question... But that's far from it. I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this happen many times... people downvote, vote to close, etc. Usually the problem is also in the author focusing on his answer, neglecting the question. But the question is what everybody looks at and scrutinizes. Self-answered questions are a rough ride on SO! One way to help yourself out is not to tag your question `java`, but add that later on, when you are satisfied with both the question and the answer text.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I'll keep it in mind for my next self-answered question! And yes, [java] questions are really prefered to be answered ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try not to use same names of built-in classes!**

Since you're using the same name of the class `java.lang.Integer`, you're hiding the built-in class with your own. So, if you're accessing an `Integer` in your example, you're accessing **your** own class that is not the built-in `java.lang.Integer` class of the JDK.

The first and the second error occur, because your class is not compatible with a real `java.lang.Integer`.
The third error occurs, because you don't have a constructor in **your** `Integer` class that accepts an `int` as parameter.

So the easiest way to get rid of the errors is just by naming your class different. For example, name it `IntegerTest` or something that fits your intention.

---

Consider the following example of a really bad practice of using the name `Integer` in different cases:

```
package Integer;

class Integer {
    public static void main(String[] lnteger) {
        System.out.println(Integer(new Integer(42)).Integer);
    }

    java.lang.Integer Integer;

    Integer(java.lang.Integer Integer) {
        this.Integer = Integer;
    }

    static Integer Integer(Integer lnteger) {
        Integer Integer; Integer:
        for (Integer = lnteger; Integer.Integer < Integer.new lnteger(lnteger).Integer.Integer; Integer.Integer++) {
            Integer(new Integer(--lnteger.Integer));
            continue Integer;
        }
        return lnteger;
    }

    class lnteger {
        Integer Integer;
        lnteger(Integer Integer) {
            this.Integer = Integer;
        }
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately**, this compiles.

You're not really able to distinguish between the different kinds of `Integer`. Without an IDE you're lost. With an IDE you're probably lost, too.

Even the formatter from **SO** can not display this in a good manner since `Integer` is a package name, class name, member name, parameter name, method name, and label name.

So give all things a **meaningful** (and at best **unique**) name to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your class to e.g. IntegerTest and all will works

```
public class IntegerTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer num1 = 42;               
}
```

}